# magento import unique key

Tags: magento

when exporting and importing data in Magento via import/export profile, products are not being updated. We selected only mapped fields. I have some idea. But am unsure.

- When you export and import, do you use the same profile? (or does the standard import function understand and import the mapped fields)
- What does Magento use as the INDEX to update the correct record. We are updating SKU, but maybe this is used as key?

Thanks, appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SKU is unique for every product. As imported product does not have id so magento can not understand that you are updating product if SKU is changed.

Comment: And with simple products under configurable products. Then why is there a box "auto generate". That has the same value as the mother product

Comment: And for the other question: do you use the same profile for import and export. Super thanks

Comment: yes, one and the same. Profile allows you to define specific settings: csv/xml, separator, etc. So if you saved profile you can use it all the time.